Query for filter blogpages by category in wagtail graphiql
Help please if i have blog category relationship then how can i fetch blogs by category. Anyone know query for that. i am using wagtail grapple
If i want to fetch blogs by category id or slug how can i do what is the graphiql query for that
This is my models
page = ParentalKey(
    "BlogPage", related_name="blog_category_relationship", on_delete=models.CASCADE
)
category = models.ForeignKey(
    "base.Category", related_name="category_blog_relationship", on_delete=models.CASCADE
)

panels = [FieldPanel("category")]

@register_paginated_query_field("blogpage")
class BlogPage(Page):
introduction = models.TextField(help_text="Text to describe the page", blank=True)
image = models.ForeignKey(
    "wagtailimages.Image",
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    related_name="+",
    help_text="Landscape mode only; horizontal width between 1000px and 3000px.",
)
body = StreamField(
    BaseStreamBlock(), verbose_name="Page body", blank=True, use_json_field=True
)
subtitle = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)
tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=BlogPageTag, blank=True)
date_published = models.DateField("Date article published", blank=True, null=True)

content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    MultipleChooserPanel(
        "blog_category_relationship",
        chooser_field_name="category",
        heading="Categories",
        label="Category",
        panels=None,
        min_num=1,
    ),
    FieldPanel("subtitle"),
    FieldPanel("introduction"),
    FieldPanel("image"),
    FieldPanel("body"),
    FieldPanel("date_published"),
    MultipleChooserPanel(
        "blog_person_relationship",
        chooser_field_name="person",
        heading="Authors",
        label="Author",
        panels=None,
        min_num=1,
    ),
    FieldPanel("tags"),
]

graphql_fields = [
    GraphQLCollection(
        GraphQLForeignKey,
        "categories",
        "base.Category"
    ),
    GraphQLString("subtitle"),
    GraphQLString("introduction"),
    GraphQLString("image_url"),
    GraphQLStreamfield("body"),
    GraphQLString("date_published"),
    GraphQLString("tags"),
    GraphQLCollection(
        GraphQLForeignKey,
        "authors",
        "base.Person"
    ),
]

search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
    index.SearchField("body"),
]

